# How to fix height, so items don't change the height of the container div?

Tags: html, css, sass, angular-material, angular-material2

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I want the house icon to not resize the containing box, I currently use a container to keep the height and the width equal.

Here is the scss:

```
$darkred: rgb(71, 0, 0);

.sidenav {
    background-color: #000860;
    left: 0;
    width: 15%;
}

.item {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-container {
    background-color: #0789f4;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 900px;
}

.container {
    background-color: $darkred;
    &:hover {
        background-color: adjust-hue($darkred, 90deg);
    }
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%; 
    position: relative; 
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" class="sidenav" 
  [fixedInViewport]="true" [fixedTopGap]="0"
  [fixedBottomGap]="0">>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content class="content-container">
    <p><mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="opened">sidenav.opened</mat-checkbox></p>
    <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">sidenav.toggle()</button></p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I would prefer the house to be the center of the div and increase the size as well, however, I can (hopefully) figure that out by myself, I've taken a look at google and other answers but they don't seem to work for me.

Comment: I think you want to use Flexbox layouts for this. This might help: http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=column&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=center&align-items=center&align-content=center&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the `padding-top: 100%;` trick you are using to create the square. Padding is always added around the content so with padding-top, your content is drawn underneath. You can change it by giving your .item class the property `position: absolute;`. This will render the item relative to it's containing block rather than in the normal flow. If you wish for the item to be rendered at the bottom of each container, you can add the `bottom: 0;` property to specify the offset. (You may also want to give it a `height: 100%` to prevent it from overflowing the container.)